# how to use 'just like'

Tags: grammar

"Just like" cannot be followed by a sentence, so 1 and 2 are correct, and 3 is incorrect. Is this correct?

> 1. This consistent exposure helps inspire them to make impactful contributions to the world as they grow up, **just like the
>    influential figures featured in the news.**

> 2. This consistent exposure helps inspire them to make impactful contributions to the world as they grow up, **just like what the
>    influential figures featured in the news do.**

> 3. This consistent exposure helps inspire them to make impactful contributions to the world as they grow up, **just like the
>    influential figures featured in the news do.**

I wrote the three sentences. "This consistent exposure" refers to the exposure to news that shapes the word today like rocket launches by Elon Musk.

Comment: Prepending ***what*** or appending ***do*** to ***the influential figures featured in the news*** doesn't change the fact that it's just a noun phrase, not an actual sentence.

Comment: *"Just like" cannot be followed by a sentence.* Says who?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, "the influential figures featured in the news do" is a noun phrase? How come?

Comment: My mistake. It's not an *independent* sentence though - the auxiliary ***do*** there can only be understood in the context of some preceding *actual* verb. But your starting point here (that *"Just like" cannot be followed by a sentence*) is still nonsense.

Comment: If you're telling us what you think the rules are, please tell us where you heard it. Kindly [edit] your question to tell us who said that "just like" cannot be followed by a sentence.

Comment: Are we dealing here with the *Winston tastes good, **like** / **as** a cigarette should* controversy of a half century ago?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to say *"Just like" cannot be followed by a sentence*. It is in the middle of your sentences!

*Just like* introduces a comparison to a person or thing - 'the influential figures' - so sentence (1) is grammatically acceptable.

I find sentence (2) clumsy - *just like what [they] do.*

Sentence (3) would be better with *as* to introduce the clause containing a verb.

> ...just as the influential figures... do.